# Search for address using SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, location

In my app I need the user to enter his home address, but I can't get any way that the addresses that are shown are only in the users region, and are full addresses, like `225e 57th st, NY, New York`.

I want to give the user all the listed options on a tableview, and to filter them as the user enters his address.

Comment: As the accepted answer says, this problem is that of address completion, and address validation. Just for future information, if you use those phrases to search you'll find good information.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can define a [local search completer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mklocalsearchcompleter):

```
let completer = MKLocalSearchCompleter()
```

And then supply the query fragment:

```
completer.delegate = self
completer.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: currentCoordinate, latitudinalMeters: 10_000, longitudinalMeters: 10_000)
completer.queryFragment = "300 S Orange"
```

And implement the `MKLocalSearchCompleterDelegate` protocol

```
extension ViewController: MKLocalSearchCompleterDelegate {

    func completerDidUpdateResults(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter) {
        let addresses = completer.results.map { result in
            result.title + ", " + result.subtitle
        }

        // use addresses, e.g. update model and call `tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

And that yields:

```
["300 S Orange Grove Blvd, Pasadena, CA, United States",
 "300 S Orange Ave, Monterey Park, CA, United States",
 "300 S Orange St, Glendale, CA, United States",
 "300 S Orange Dr, Los Angeles, CA, United States",
 "300 S Orange Ave, Azusa, CA, United States",
 "300 S Orange Grove Ave, Los Angeles, CA, United States",
 "300 S Orange Ave, Brea, CA, United States",
 "300 S Orange Ave, Fullerton, CA, United States",
 "300 S Orange St, Orange, CA, United States",
 "300 S Orange Ave, Rialto, CA, United States",
 "300 S Orange Ave, Fallbrook, CA, United States",
 "300 S Orange St, Escondido, CA, United States",
 "300 S Orange Ave, El Cajon, CA, United States",
 "300 S Orange Cir, Tulare, CA, United States",
 "300 S Orange Ave, Exeter, CA, United States"]
```

---

Or else, you can do a local search:

```
let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
request.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: currentCoordinate, latitudinalMeters: 10_000, longitudinalMeters: 10_000)
request.naturalLanguageQuery = "300 S Pumpkin"

let formatter = CNPostalAddressFormatter()
formatter.style = .mailingAddress

let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
search.start { response, error in
    let addresses = response?.mapItems.compactMap { item -> String? in
        return item.placemark.postalAddress.flatMap {
            formatter.string(from: $0).replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: ", ")
        }
    }
    print(addresses)
}
```

Now, I’m using the Contacts framework’s formatter (which also exposes the `postalAddress` property on the placemark), but you can format these any way you want. But, assuming it finds matches, that shows something like:

```
["300 S Pumpkin Blvd, Los Angeles, CA  92108, United States",
 "300 S Pumpkin Pkwy, Los Angeles, CA  92103, United States",
 "300 S Pumpkin Dr, San Gabriel, CA  91776, United States"])
```

Now, whether you want the `FormattedAddressLines`, or extract the individual components from the `addressDictionary` is up to you, but hopefully this illustrates the idea.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working just as i wanted it to, but when im using the MKLocalSearchRequest the most addresses that i get is 10, there is a way to cancel the limit?

Comment: No, I don't believe so. Obviously, `MKLocalSearchCompleter` can return more than 10 (and if the address being entered is incomplete, I actually think it's better at handling partial entries).