# Can I do a location search in Swift without using the map?

Tags: ios, swift, search, location, mapkit

What I'm trying to create in Swift 3.0 is a simple location search, based on current location (or a specified one), for a predefined range (e.g. 100 km). I don't want any results that are outside of that range. I don't want to see the map, put any pins on it, etc. Just want the search, and then return the result. Is this possible with mapkit? Every example or tutorial I have found starts with the map and uses the map to get the region/span, then returns to the map with the result. In trying out some of those examples, the search is not restricted to the map region, as I'm getting results in other countries. What I want is a single screen search that simply returns a selected location. No map. No results from the other side of the world. Should I be using something other than mapkit or can I accomplish this without the mapview?

Edit:
With the info provided by @Rob, I'm up to here...

```
extension LocationSearchTable : UISearchResultsUpdating {

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        var localRegion: MKCoordinateRegion
        let distance: CLLocationDistance = 1200

        let currentLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: 50.412165, longitude: -104.66087)

        localRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(currentLocation, distance, distance)

        print(localRegion)

        guard let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }

        let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBarText
        request.region = localRegion
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)

        search.start { response, _ in
            guard let response = response else {
                return
            }
            self.matchingItems = response.mapItems
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm still a bit confused. It still seems to bring up results from all over. For example, if I was looking for the address 19 Rendek Crescent based on a location in Regina, SK, here are the results as I type:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Why is it returning locations outside of Regina, and why do Rae St and Read Ave come up before Rendek does?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What did not work or what error was raised?

Comment: Just build your own `MKCoordinateRegion`, e.g. with `MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance`, and use that. No need to use a map view.

Comment: Also, regarding getting results across the world, what API are you using? The [`geocodeAddressString`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/clgeocoder/1423509-geocodeaddressstring) will look for an address anywhere. But [`MKLocalSearch`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mklocalsearch) will use the [`region`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mklocalsearchrequest/1451919-region) you supply to the [`MKLocalSearchRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mklocalsearchrequest).

Comment: @Rob, I think I'm on the right track. I have it working without the mapview, except that without specifying the mapView.region, the results are all over. If I understand correctly what you're saying, I just need to define this region manually and set the request.region to that?

Comment: Yes, set the request's `region`.

Comment: @Rob, I just updated my question with my current results. Am I specifying the region incorrectly, or is this just the way the search works?

Comment: If you're trying to search completions to an address being typed in, consider `MKLocalSearchCompleter`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39948228/1271826

Comment: ok. Thanks. That will work.

Comment: I think maybe your simulator location setup?

Answer (score 1):

You'd start out by creating a location class to keep your cell organized. (Don't forget to import MapKit to these view controllers)

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class Location: NSObject {
    var locationName: String!
    var location: String!

    init(locationName: String, location: String) {
        self.locationName = locationName
        self.location = location
    }
}
```

Then, create an array that will store your data inside your TableViewController:

```
var locations = [Location]()
```

You also need a configure cell function in your cell class.

```
func configureLocationCell(locationName: String, location: String) {
         self.myLocationNameLabel.text = locationName
         self.myLocationLabel.text = location
    }
```

Then, perform a MKLocalSearch request to find your locations: (put this inside a textfield did change function)

```
func performSearchRequest() {
        let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        guard let coordinate = locationManager.location?.coordinate else { return }

        request.naturalLanguageQuery = "\(myTextField.text)"
        request.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate, 3200, 3200)
        // about a couple miles around you

        MKLocalSearch(request: request).start { (response, error) in
            guard error == nil else { return }
            guard let response = response else { return }
            guard response.mapItems.count > 0 else { return }

            let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(response.mapItems.count)))
            let locationItems = response.mapItems[randomIndex]

            for location in response.locationItems {
                let location = Location(locationName: location.name!, location: "\(gyms.placemark.subLocality!)", "\(gyms.placemark.locality!)")
                self.locations.append(location)
                self.myTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally, in your TableViewController **number of cells** function, 
**return locations.count**.

One last thing: in your **cell for row at index path** function, access the data by typing:

```
let location = locations[indexPath.row]
cell.configureLocationCell(locationName: location.locationName, location: location)
```