# How to get more results from CoreLocations geocodeAddressString?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I have an application that allows the user to enter some an address, I then want to basically serve up a list of possible addresses that they might be referring to and so that I can use it in MapKit readable form.

My current approach is so:

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate{

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(textField.text!, completionHandler: {(placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: Error?) -> Void in
            if let placemarks = placemarks{
                //send placemarks to table view
                //however, placemarks only contains one element  
                //(even when textfield contains very generic text)
            } else{ }   
        })
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to get more results? Using Apple's Map app and they load 15 results from entering just 4 numbers, how can I get my app to display this many results? Is Apple using something other than coreLocation to bring up possible locations?

Comment: In terms of getting more than 15, not that I know of. Bu if the search is constrained to a particular area, I sometimes find that using [`MKLocalSearchCompleter`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mklocalsearchcompleter) is better. It depends upon the desired UX. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/39948228/1271826.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I think the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/) for iOS should help you get what you need. I do not believe Apple has an equivalent API (unless you want plain language searches a la MKLocalSearchRequest).

Comment: still getting same result when expanding the region

Comment: Edited answer, I misunderstood your question. I think you the Google Places API for iOS should help.

Comment: Also, I accidentally edited your question. Sorry about that.

Comment: no worries, I will go ahead and look at the places api, thanks for the heads up! Also, do you know if I can quickly generate a coreloaction placemark if using the places api?

Comment: Yes. The flow would be: User types address -> Google provides suggestions -> User chooses address -> Get placemark with address/coordinates. The only issue you may run into is mismatched addresses between Google and AppleMaps. I've only run into this problem a few times, and even then, the Apple placemark was only slightly different than the Google Maps address.